# vertical alignment of block element

Tags: html, css

how can i vertical align this image that is already horizontally aligned with display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

NOTE THAT I CANT USE top:50% left:50% transform: translate(-50%,-50%) or any display with flex methods.

**fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/3mLsL9t5/2/

**CSS**

```
.myContainer {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: lightblue;
 }

.myImage {
 width: auto;
 max-width: 20px;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 22px;
 border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Updated my answer showing how-to with block element, though the inline versions is recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go ... just let the image be an image (inline) and add this to your `.myContainer`

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Sample snippet

```css
.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.myImage {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<div class='myContainer'>
  <img class='myImage' src='https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/images/sidebar-smashingconf-oxford.png'>
</div>
```

---

Update

Or you can use `line-height`

```css
.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 111px;
}

.myImage {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<div class='myContainer'>
  <img class='myImage' src='https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/images/sidebar-smashingconf-oxford.png'>
</div>
```

If you still need some *block* behavior, you can add `display: inline-block;` to the image

---

Update 2

As you asked about block element, I added a version showing that too.

```css
.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.myImage {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<div class='myContainer'>
  <img class='myImage' src='https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/images/sidebar-smashingconf-oxford.png'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below css

```
.myImage {
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
}
.myContainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: OP stated that he can't use `top: 50%` or `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: for some strange reason the vertical alignment does not work on my site - but works in a fiddle :/ https://jsfiddle.net/3mLsL9t5/4/ <- works, not sure why it dosent work for me, there are no secret parent divs i havent mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using the CSS for the image:

```
position: absolute,
left:0,
right:0,
top:0,
bottom:0,
margin:auto
```

and `position:relative` for the container.

```css
.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.myImage {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='myContainer'>
  <img class='myImage' src='https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/images/sidebar-smashingconf-oxford.png'>
</div>
```

Please check here [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mLsL9t5/5/)